# printing a reverse sentence with punctuation c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I'm trying to reverse a sentence like the following:
The input:

> my name is john. i am 23 years old.

The output:

> .old years 23 am i .john is name my

I can't figure it out how to switch the dot at the end.
I tried using `Split` but it always return the dot at the end of the word.

```
 string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
 Array.Reverse(words);
 return string.Join(" ", words);
```

Comment: Why don't you split on dots first, and *then* do what you do now. and later put it back together with dots in the end.

Comment: `return String.Join(" ", words.Split(' ').Reverse().Select(x => x.EndsWith(".") ? "." + x.TrimEnd('.') : x));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add extra logic to move period ('.') before the word starts, like

```
var sentence ="my name is john. i am 23 years old.";  //Input string
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');                //Split sentence into words
Array.Reverse(words);                                //Revere the array of words

//If word starts with . then start your word with period and trim end.
var result = words.Select(x => x.EndsWith('.') ? $".{x.Trim('.')}" : x);  
                            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^This was missing
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result));
```

---

Elegant one liner approach suggested by [@metroSmurf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9664/metro-smurf) in the comment section

```
var result = sentence.Split(' ')  //Split array with space as a delimiter.
    .Reverse()  //Use IEnumerable<T>.Reverse to reverse the array. No need to use Array.Reverse()
    .Select(x => x.EndsWith('.') ? $".{x.Trim('.')}" : x); //Apply same logic mentioned above.
```

[Try online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/owI4xw)

Comment: No need for `Array.Reverse`: `sentence..Split(' ').Reverse().Select(x =>...)` and use `.TrimEnd` instead of `.Trim`.

Comment: @MetroSmurf, Thanks for your one liner solution, I added it in my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try combination of *Linq* and *Regular Expressions*:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string source = "my name is john. i am 23 years old.";

  // .old years 23 am i .john is name my
  string result = string.Join(" ", Regex
    .Matches(source, @"\S+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"^(.*?)(\p{P}+)$", "$2$1"))
    .Reverse());
```

Here we use *two* patterns: a simple one `"\S+"` which matches any characters which are not whitespaces. The next pattern `^(.*?)(\p{P}+)$` worth explaining:

```
^(.*?)(\p{P}+)$
```

here

```
^        - anchor, start of the string 
(.*?)    - group #1: any symbols, but as few as possible
(\p{P}+) - group #2: one or more punctuation symbols
$        - anchor, end of the string
```

and when matched we *swap* these groups: `"&2&1"`

**Demo:**

```
private static string Solve(string source) => string.Join(" ", Regex
  .Matches(source, @"\S+")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"^(.*?)(\p{P}+)$", "$2$1"))
  .Reverse());

...

string[] tests = new string[] {
  "my name is john. i am 23 years old.",
  "It's me, here am I!",
  "Test...",
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,-35} => {Solve(test)}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
my name is john. i am 23 years old. => .old years 23 am i .john is name my
It's me, here am I!                 => !I am here ,me It's
Test...                             => ...Test
```

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar: I've got a lot from https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: I bookmarked this URL. Thanks, @DmitryBychenko.

Answer (score 0):

You are reversing words separated by space (in `old.` the point is part of the word). If you want to reverse the points too you want to consider them as words (sperated by space):

```
public static class TextExtensions
{
    public static string PointTrick(this string str) => str.Replace(".", " .");

    public static string PointUntrick(this string str) => str.Replace(". ", ".");

    public static string ReverseWords(this string str) => string.Join(" ", str.Split(" ").Reverse());
}
```

Those tests pass.

```
[TestClass]
public class SOTests
{
    private string GetReversedWithPointTrick(string input) => input.PointTrick().ReverseWords().PointUntrick();


    [TestMethod]
    public void ReverseWordsTest()
    {
        var sut = "three two. one";
        var expected = "one two. three";

        var result = sut.ReverseWords();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ReverseWords_PointTrick_Test()
    {
        var sut = "my name is john. i am 23 years old.";
        var expected = ".old years 23 am i .john is name my";

        var result = GetReversedWithPointTrick(sut);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because someone always has to post a LINQ version of these things

```
sentence.Split().Reverse.Select(w => w[^1] == '.' ? ('.' + w[..^1]) : w);
```

Split without any argument splits on whitespace, Reverse is a LINQ thing that reverses the input and then we just have a bit of logic that asks if the last (^1 is from the indexes and ranges feature of c# 9, meaning "one from the end") char is a dot, move it to the start (concat a dot plus all the string up to 1 from the end) othwise just output the word..

And all that remains is to string join it, which you know how to do: `string.Join(" ", ...)`